# Change field in one model while adding an entry in another model automatically in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models in my django webapp. One is Detector which has a detector_id and current_location and the other is LocationTransfer which stores the changes to the location of each detector (one-to-many relationship with a timestamp). Thus LocationTransfer has detector_id (fk), new_location and a timestamp.

The django-admin site provides me with a form to add another field in the LocationTransfer, however, while filling this form I also want to automatically change the current_location in Detector model of that detector_id. This I have to ensure because the person using the admin interface might forget to edit both the models.

How do I enable this feature?

No foreign link would work, obviously. Also it's fairly straightforward to do it in the normal website, but I do not know how to enable this in case of an admin.

```
class Detector(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField('Detector name or ID', max_length=256, primary_key=True) 

class LocationTransfer(models.Model):
    detector_id = models.ForeignKey('Detector', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transfer_datetime = models.DateTimeField('Date and time', default=datetime.now)
    destination_location = models.CharField('To', max_length=256)
```

I want the current_location of an object models.Detector change as a person adds a an entry for LocationTransfer in the admin-forms.

Comment: you want to change Detector `current_location` with LocationTransfer `destination_location` . when saving LactionTransfer object from admin ?

Comment: Yes Sumeet Kumar. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You can use `pre_save` signal or you can override save method in model class or if you want it from admin you can override `model_save`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the pre_save or overriding save method?